# What is that sign in the context of vectors?

Tags: vector-spaces

Suppose $v = (0, -5, 5, -6, -7)$ a vector.

I need to find $$\|v\|_1, \|v\|_2, \|v\|_9, \|v\|_\infty.$$

can you please explain me what does $\|v\|_i$ mean?

Comment: $\|v\|_p := \sqrt[p]{|v_1|^p + \ldots + |v_5|^p}$, $\|v\|_\infty := \max\{|v_1|, \ldots, |v_5|\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably the [p-norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space):
$$\|v\|_p = \left(|v_1|^p + | v_2|^p + \cdots \right)^{1/p}$$
Where for $p\to\infty$, it's equal to the maximum norm:
$$\|v\|_\infty = \max\{|v_1|,|v_2|,  \ldots \}$$

Comment: $|v_1|^p$ means the absolute value raised to p?

Comment: @user1798362 - yes it does.

Answer (score 3):

Typically it is the $p$-norm; if $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ then

$$\Vert\mathbf{x}\Vert_p:=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^p\right)^{1/p}$$

and

$$\Vert\mathbf{x}\Vert_\infty:=\max\{|x_1|,\dots,|x_k|\}$$

Bonus points: can you figure out why the infinity norm is defined like that?